# Help with proof for the contrapositive of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Fermat's Little Theorem:

> If $p$ is prime and $a$ is an integer relatively prime to $p$, then $a^{(p-1)} \equiv 1\pmod p$

Contrapositive of Fermat's Little Theorem:

> If $a$ is an integer relatively prime to $p$ such that $a^{(p-1)} \not\equiv 1\pmod p$, then $p$ is not prime (i.e. $p$ is composite)

Assuming my contrapositive statement is correctly formed, my thought process to prove it is to use proof by contradiction. I'd suppose $a^{(p-1)} \equiv 1\pmod p$ is true and demonstrate how this is impossible for when $p$ is not prime. Is this a correct line of thought?  If so, how would I demonstrate that $a^{(p-1)} \equiv 1\pmod p$ doesn't work when $p$ is not prime?

Please note that I have absolutely zero understanding of group theory (which is a common thing people use to prove modular arithmetic theories), so explanations using it will be lost on me.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Relative to "If so, how would I demonstrate that a(p−1)≡1 (mod p) doesn't work when p is not prime?", sometimes it is true when p isn't prime. See the Carmichael numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive to the logical implication $a\Rightarrow b$, namely $\lnot b\Rightarrow\lnot a$ is *always equivalent* to the first statement.  Thus any proof of one will suffice as a proof of the other.

My favorite proof can be found in Lang's *Algebra*, and simply uses the fact that the multiplicative group of the field $\mathbb F_p$ has order $p-1$.  Then one can just apply Lagrange's theorem, which guarantees, well, none other than Fermat's little theorem.  For the order of any nonzero element of $\mathbb F_p$ must, by Lagrange, divide $p-1$.

---

Let me see if I can avoid the group theory here. If we follow
Vinogradov, in his *Elements of Number Theory*, page $48$, the
approach is to prove the more general

> **Euler's theorem**: We assume $(a,m)=1$ and let $x$ run
> through a reduced system of residues $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_{\varphi(m)}$;
> then $ax$ will run through those same residues, but in general in a
> different order: $\rho_1,\rho_2,\dots,\rho_{\varphi(m)}$.   Then we
> multiply the congruences $ar_1\equiv\rho_1\pmod
> m,ar_2\equiv\rho_2\pmod
>  m,\dots,ar_{\varphi(m)}\equiv\rho_{\varphi(m)}\pmod m$, to get
> $a^{\varphi(m)}r_1r_2\dots r_{\varphi(m)}\equiv
> \rho_1\rho_2\dots\rho_{\varphi(m)}\pmod m$.  Finally, divide each side
> by $r_1r_2\dots r_{\varphi(m)}$, to get $a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv1\pmod
>  m$.
>
> Here we have used *Euler's totient function* $\varphi(m)$, which
> returns the number of numbers $n\le m$ such that $(n,m)=1$.

This is essentially the way Euler proved it, I think.

> Now **Fermat's little theorem** drops out when we replace $m$ by $p$,
> since $\varphi(p)=p-1$.

Comment: I'm studying Applied Math and required to learn about cryptography, so Fermat's Little Theorem is necessary. However, at no point in my entire program do they teach me about group theory. I'm expected to understand the theorems of modular antiemetic without using it. Most Pure Math concepts are useless in the real world so my program tries to avoid them unless absolutely necessary (an opinion I support)

Comment: Okay @BobbyB  Well I did my best to show a number theoretic proof.

Comment: I do appreciate the help. It seems like your proof demonstrates the existence of Euler's Theorem (a general case of Fermat's Little Theorem). But I don't understand the last sentence, "now Fermat's little theorem drops out when we replace $m$ by $p$, since $\varphi(p)=p-1$". Could you elaborate on what you mean by "drops out"? How does this lead to the conclusion that the contrapositive of FLT is valid?

Comment: Like I said an implication and its contrapositive are always equivalent.  So, admittedly, I have gone ahead and proved Euler, which implies FLT, which in turn implies its contrapositive.  It drops out because, Euler's theorem applies more generally.  Note that there are $p-1$ numbers less than $p$ which are relatively prime to it.  In Euler's theorem, $m$ doesn't have to be prime!

Comment: It seem as if there is no direct proof to the contrapositive then. We simply have to go by the philosophical logic that when a conditional statement is true, so too is it's contrapositive. Not very satisfying from a math standpoint, but I guess that's how it is sometimes.

Comment: Just remember,  a statement and its contrapositive are two different ways of saying the same thing.  The contrapositive of a theorem is that same theorem.   That's all it really boils down to.  If you want to do a proof by contradiction,  assume FLT doesn't apply, and show $(a ,p)\ne1$.

Comment: The proof by contradiction would be to assume FLT doesn't apply,  and show that either  $p $ is not prime, or $(a,p)\ne1$.  (I forgot the last part. )